# What is the correct way to interact between views in MVC in Java?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jpanel

I have 2 `JPanel`: **Panel_S**, **Panel_P**. The 1st listens to Station events and the 2nd listens to Passenger events.
When new passenger is created it is added to `JList` in **Panel_P**. When passenger finished "going" to station by `goToStation` and getting in line by `station.addPassenger(this);` the station's event `fireAddPassengerEvent` is fired and the passenger is added to `JList` in **Panel_S**. Now, I need some how to remove the passenger from `JList` in **Panel_P** because it finished "going" and entered the queue in station. What is the correct way to implement this? Does **Panel_S** should "tell" **Panel_P** to remove the passenger from its list once **Panel_S** adds passenger to its list?

If you didn't understood my question please tell me and I'll try to explain myself better.

```
public class Passenger extends Thread {
    private Station station;
    private Vector<PassengerEventsViewListener> viewListeners;

    public Passenger(Station station)
    {
        this.station = station;
    }
    private void getInLineInStation()
    {
        station.addPassenger(this);
    }
    private void fireArrivedToStationEvent(EventArgs<Passenger> args)
    {       
       for (PassengerEventsViewListener l : viewListeners) {
          l.arrivedToStationEvent(args);
       }
    }
    private void goToStation()
    {
        //going
        fireArrivedToStationEvent(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       goToStation();
       getInLineInStation();
    }
}

public class Station {
     private Vector<StationEventsViewListener> viewListeners;

     private void fireAddPassengerEvent(Passenger passenger)
     {      
         for (StationEventsViewListener l : viewListeners) {
             l.addPassengerEvent(passenger);
         } 
     }
     public synchronized boolean addPassenger(Passenger p)
     {
          passengersInQueue.addLast(passenger);     
          fireAddPassengerEvent(passenger);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your views should not communicate and should not be coupled. Only the models talk and see each other. Each model's view changes accordingly.

Back to your problem. `Panel_P` should be linked to a model that contains information about passengers. In the other hand, `Panel_S` should be linked to a model that contains information about stations. Now when a new passenger arrives to a station, the `passenger` model should notify the `station` model of the new arrival. `Panel_S` can then be updated from `station` model without caring about `passenger` model nor its view (`Panel_P`)

Answer (score 2):

> Does Panel_S should ''tell'' Panel_P to remove the passenger from its list once Panel_S adds passenger to its list?

In MVC: no. This is typically what MVC tries to avoid: coupling views together. Like always in MVC, the solution is to make the model notify this information. Upon notification, the Panel_P will automatically remove the passenger from its list.